# Load data on scrolling right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I created a page in which to view data we scroll on right instead of down. Now I tired to load data while scrolling instead of loading the entire page at first. I can work around if it is down scroll. This is the code that I'm working on:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var win = $(window);

win.scroll(function() {     
    if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) 
       {
        $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'load.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(html) {
                $('#data').append(html);
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

I referred and worked on this code from [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/). Now i need to load data when I'm scrolling right. I tried taking the difference in width but it is not working. Is there any other work around ?

Comment: Look at [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/).

Comment: if you have scrollbars, you can try to look at https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/

Comment: your scrolling function are working fine check with debugger where its going false.

Comment: There is no problem with my scrolling function but i need to load data only on scrolling which I couldn't do. I need to write function for that.

Answer (score 0):

may be something like this ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul').scroll(function(event) {
    if (this.scrollWidth - this.clientWidth - this.scrollLeft < 50) {
        $(this).append('<li>data 1</li><li>data 2</li><li>data 3</li><li>data 4</li>')
    }
});
});
```